# why am I getting a 406 code from facebook when trying to share a page?

Tags: facebook

I'm getting a 406 code from facebook on all of my pages. When I look at the source everything looks good and we use gzip, loads in 1 or 2 seconds, use full Open Graph properties
Here is a sample link https://raddezigns.com/13538/christian-biker-kneeling-at-the-cross-biker-car-window-decals-stickers
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: not sure if your question is missing a lot of info that would make an answer more easily identifiable, or if it's just a spam post to promote that link

Comment: What other info do you want? Open the page and view the source

Comment: go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ and enter that url to see what facebook replies.

Comment: Bad Response Code
URL returned a bad HTTP response code. Response Code 406

Comment: Yea you have to fix your server to not return 406. Why your server returns 406 we have no idea

Comment: It doesn't return a 406 on anything other than facebooks bot. Search engines and everyone else can access it with no problem. It's something that facebook's bot is looking for that I don't have or something isn't formatted right. I don't know what the problem is. That's why I'm asking for help from someone that has had the same problem with the facebook bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue I have fixed the problem. Facebook sends "php" as it's user-agent. If you have modsecurity enabled on your server it will kick back a 406 error with "Matched phrase "PHP" at REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent." as the justification. To fix it you will have to write a rule for modsecurity to allow it or disable modsecurity. Facebook should really modify their headers so that this doesn't happen and you are able to run your firewall as it should be.